# I don't know how to process Python txt file input data

Tags: python, matrix, input

input.txt

```
3 3
1 3 3 | 3
2 7 8 | 4
1 5 1 | 5
```

I want to read it through Python file reading and then divide it into two matrices,
like

```
1 3 3
2 7 8
1 5 1

3
4
5
```

but I don't know how.

```
f=open("input.txt","r") # open input file
line = f.readline()

row = list(map(int, line.split()))[0]
col = list(map(int, line.split()))[1]

print("row = ",row, "col = ",col)
main_matrix=[[]]
sub_matrix=[]
tmp_matrix=[[]]

for i in range(0,row):
    line = f.readline()
    tmp_matrix = line[0:row+2]
    tmp_matrix = (list(map(int, tmp_matrix.split())))
    main_matrix=tmp_matrix
print(main_matrix)
```

I thought this would separate the main matrix, but the result was that only the last row was separated

Comment: After the readline, you need to use `line.split()` to split the line into words.  Then the first 3 words are your 3x3 values, and the 5th word is your 1x3 value.  And in your code, you are overwriting the matrix with the last row, instead of appending to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to handle your input, using the suggestions from my comment.

```
f=open("input.txt","r")
line = f.readline().strip().split()
rows = int(line[0])
cols = int(line[1])

print("row = ",rows, "col = ",cols)
main_matrix=[]
sub_matrix=[]

for line in f:
    parts = line.strip().split()
    main_matrix.append( [int(k) for k in parts[:cols]] )
    sub_matrix.append( int(parts[-1]) )

print(main_matrix)
print(sub_matrix)
```

Output:

```
row =  3 col =  3
[[1, 3, 3], [2, 7, 8], [1, 5, 1]]
[3, 4, 5]
```